# Dynamic query generation in U SQL

Tags: u-sql

My requirement is to dynamically schematize the extract statements in U SQL for separate files according to the metadata information of each file present in external data source. Please see if anyone can help here.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

1. Write a U-SQL script that reads the meta data information from the external data source which then creates the U-SQL script you want to run.
2. Write some custom code in your favorite scripting language (PowerShell, node.js, Python etc.) to generate the script and submit it.

Comment: For #2, one could use a template engine like T4 or Mustache to query the datasource and generate the USQL script.